# How to force-commit two files without branching

Tags: git

I have a project that has some special files (not text files, but binary files like images), which I'd like to commit as is, without merging. I just need to update them on reposiroty with new files keeping their filenames.
What would be the best way to do this?
Should I create a branch, then commit, then push? But if it tries to merge those files I'm afraid they're going to break.
I just want to force commit them, in the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually git already supports it.

You can mark them as binary in the `.gitattributes` file. After that, git won't compute or print a diff for changes in this file, neither do automatic merge.

In the file `.gitattributes` in the root of git repository just as `.gitignore`, add things such as:

```
*.jpg binary
*.png binary
```

Comment: thanks! but what should I do next? I've updated .gitattributes. Updated files in my windows files explorer. Now should I "git commit" those? (these files are already added to the repository I just need to update them).

Comment: Not sure if I get your question correctly. You mean how to commit these files? Mark files as binary will avoid automatically diff and merge. So you can just commit these files as any others without worrying about that your files are broken by automatic merge.